# Index array using array of unique values

Tags: python, numpy, loops, indexing

I have three arrays, such that:

```
Data_Arr = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5])
ID_Arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
Value_Arr = np.array([0.1, 0.6, 0.3, 0.8, 0.2])
```

I want to create a new array which has the dimensions of Data, but where each element is from Values, using the index position in ID. So far I have this in a loop, but its very slow as my Data array is very large:

```
out = np.zeros_like(Data_Arr, dtype=np.float)

for i in range(len(Data_Arr)):
    out[i] = Values_Arr[ID_Arr==Data_Arr[I]]
```

is there a more pythonic way of doing this and avoiding this loop (doesn't have to use numpy)?

Actual data looks like:

```
Data_Arr = [ 852116  852116  852116 ... 1001816 1001816 1001816]
ID_Arr = [ 852116  852117  852118 ... 1001814 1001815 1001816]
Value_Arr = [1.5547194 1.5547196 1.5547197 ... 1.5536859 1.5536858 1.5536857]
```

shapes are:

```
Data_Arr = (4021165,)
ID_Arr = (149701,)
Value_Arr = (149701,)
```

Comment: I'm not going to offer this as an answer because it uses more memory and might not be any faster, but I note that `d = dict(zip(ID_Arr, Value_Arr)); print([d[i] for i in Data_Arr])` would be equivalent (although not utilising numpy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ID_Arr` is sorted, we can directly use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) and index `Value_Arr` with the result:

```
Value_Arr[np.searchsorted(ID_Arr, Data_Arr)]
array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8, 0.8,
       0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
```

If `ID_Arr` isn't sorted (*note*: in case there may be out of bounds indices, we should remove them, see divakar's answer):

```
s_ind = ID_Arr.argsort()
ss = np.searchsorted(ID_Arr, Data_Arr, sorter=s_ind)
out = Value_Arr[s_ind[ss]]
```

---

Checking with the arrays suggested by alaniwi:

```
Data_Arr = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5])
ID_Arr = array([2, 1, 3, 4, 5])
Value_Arr = np.array([0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.2])

out_op = np.zeros_like(Data_Arr, dtype=np.float)
for i in range(len(Data_Arr)):
    out_op[i] = Value_Arr[ID_Arr==Data_Arr[i]]

s_ind = ID_Arr.argsort()
ss = np.searchsorted(ID_Arr, Data_Arr, sorter=s_ind)
out_answer = Value_Arr[s_ind[ss]]

np.array_equal(out_op, out_answer)
#True
```

Comment: Can you make a way that does not depend on `ID_Arr` being sorted? For example, if you permute both `ID_Arr` and `Value_Arr` in the same way (for example, swap the first two elements in both cases), it should not change the result.

Comment: The output is still not agreeing with the code in the question when I try it with lists that have been permuted as described.

Comment: This is using the order that would sort `ID_Arr` for the searchsorted. Hence produces the same output for unordered `ID_Arr`. If you change `Value_Arr`, of course the output is different, we are using the result of searchsorted to index this array @alaniwi

Comment: I was swapping the first two elements of each of the two arrays: `ID_Arr = array([2, 1, 3, 4, 5])` and `Value_Arr = array([0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.2])`. Code in question still gives `array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6, ...])` but yours gives `array([0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.1, 0.1, ...]).

Comment: @yatu You need to index back with `argsort()` indices I suppose.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out @alaniwi should work now for the mentioned case

Comment: @yatu And then take care of out of bounds cases and any non-mtaching ones if any :)

Comment: Which then becomes your first approach :D I think I might just warn about it and reference to your post @Divakar

Comment: @yatu I haven't really looked at your algorithm, but the output is looking good now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! ID_Arr should always be sorted but its great to have the alternative too

Answer (score 1):

Based off approaches from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62658135/), here are the adaptations.

#### Approach #1

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/62658135/ @Divakar  
a,b,invalid_specifier = ID_Arr, Data_Arr, 0

sidx = a.argsort()
idx = np.searchsorted(a,b,sorter=sidx)

# Remove out of bounds indices as they wont be matches
idx[idx==len(a)] = 0

# Get traced back indices corresponding to original version of a
idx0 = sidx[idx]

# Mask out invalid ones with invalid_specifier and return
out = np.where(a[idx0]==b, Values_Arr[idx0], invalid_specifier)
```

#### Approach #2

Lookup based -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/62658135/ @Divakar    
def find_indices_lookup(a,b,invalid_specifier=-1):
    # Setup array where we will assign ranged numbers
    N = max(a.max(), b.max())+1
    lookup = np.full(N, invalid_specifier)

    # We index into lookup with b to trace back the positions. Non matching ones
    # would have invalid_specifier values as wount had been indexed by ranged ones
    lookup[a] = np.arange(len(a))
    indices  = lookup[b]
    return indices                     

idx = find_indices_lookup(ID_Arr, Data_Arr)
out = np.where(idx!=-1, Values_Arr[idx], 0)
```

**Faster/simpler variant**

And a simplified and hopefully faster version would be a direct lookup of values -

```
a,b,invalid_specifier = ID_Arr, Data_Arr, 0

N = max(a.max(), b.max())+1
lookup = np.zeros(N, dtype=Values_Arr.dtype)
lookup[ID_Arr] = Values_Arr
out = lookup[Data_Arr]
```

If all values from `ID_Arr` are guaranteed to be in `Data_Arr`, we can use `np.empty` in place of `np.zeros` for the array-assignment and thus gain further perf. boost.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want:

```
out = Value_Arr[ID_Arr[Data_Arr - 1] - 1]
```

Note that the `- 1` are due to the fact that Python/Numpy is `0`-based index.

Comment: This does not work in the general case -- it is making assumptions that `ID_Arr` values are a sequence of integers starting at 1.